# Issue after I deploy the app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a web app I'm currently working on, I just came across of an issue right after the system finishes executing git push heroku master.  In development, the app works fine. I've already changed the db to PostgreSQL, so there's no issue to push. But after the push, when I try to see the app online, it tells me there's an error, when I search the heroku logs via the command `Heroku logs --tail`, here's what I found for errors:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 866ms
    at parse_error (/tmp/execjs20130330-2-1s2w7pb.js:1824:17)
    at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20130330-2-1s2w7pb.js:1720:22)
ActionView::Template::Error (Unexpected character '#' (line: 11021, col: 1, pos: 312418)
Error
    at js_error (/tmp/execjs20130330-2-1s2w7pb.js:1728:15)

    at Object.semicolon [as 1] (/tmp/execjs20130330-2-1s2w7pb.js:2221:38)
    at simple_statement (/tmp/execjs20130330-2-1s2w7pb.js:2362:35)
    at /tmp/execjs20130330-2-1s2w7pb.js:2265:32

    at Object.next_token [as input] (/tmp/execjs20130330-2-1s2w7pb.js:2070:17)
    at next (/tmp/execjs20130330-2-1s2w7pb.js:2175:37)
    at /tmp/execjs20130330-2-1s2w7pb.js:2753:32
  (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)):
    9: <body>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag

    4:   <title>Pinsvault</title>
```

I can't see where to go to fix, it seems something with JavaScript, but I don't have anything like that in development.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not closing your `javascript_include_tag`, try adding `%>`

```
<%= javascript_include_tag %>
```

You can try to verify this locally with the Chrome inspector's console tab. See if you have any javascript errors there.